# HashRouter links do not return correct page, instead it stays on the home page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am incorporating HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter in React so I can host my website on GitHub Pages, however, even on local host, when I click one of my links, the page just returns back to the Home page instead of the actual page I need to go to.

The path changes according to what I click, however, there is no Hash symbol in the URL, all while being on the home page.

I've looked all over the internet, however I can't find a solution. Is there anything I'm missing?

```
import { HashRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './style.css'
import Home from './pages/Home';
import EventPage from './pages/EventPage';
import musicEvents from './events';
function App() {

    // Returns Main application
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <>
            <nav id='header'>
            <a href="/" id='home-link'>
                <h1 id='page-title'>Concert Portfolio</h1>
            </a>
            </nav>

            {/* Sets up routes */}
            <Router>
              <Routes>
                <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} />
                {/* Maps over events from musicEvents object and creates a route based on each event */}
                {musicEvents.map((musicEvent) => {
                return <Route path={`/${musicEvent.path}`} element={<EventPage />} key={Math.random()} />
                })}
              </Routes>
            </Router>
        </>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `a` tag with `react-router-dom` use `Link` instead

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, as Konrad Linkowski mentioned, I should use `Link` instead of `a` tags and that direct me to fixing the issues.